# How can I improve the native query for a table with 7 millions rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, nativequery

I have the below view(table) in my database(SQL SERVER).

[image]

I want to retrieve 2 things from this table.

- The object which has the latest booking date for each Product number.
  It will return the objects = {0001, 2, 2019-06-06 10:39:58} and {0003, 2, 2019-06-07 12:39:58}.
- If all the step number has no booking date for a Product number, it wil return the object with Step number = 1. It will return the object = {0002, 1, NULL}.

The view has 7.000.000 rows. I must do it by using native query.

The first query that retrieves the product with the latest booking date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM TABLE t
WHERE t.BOOKING_DATE = (SELECT max(tbl.BOOKING_DATE) FROM TABLE tbl WHERE t.PRODUCT_NUMBER = tbl.PRODUCT_NUMBER)
```

The second query that retrieves the product with booking date NULL and Step number = 1;

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM TABLE t
WHERE (SELECT max(tbl.BOOKING_DATE) FROM TABLE tbl WHERE t.PRODUCT_NUMBER = tbl.PRODUCT_NUMBER) IS NULL AND t.STEP_NUMBER = 1
```

I tried using a single query, but it takes too long.
For now I use 2 query for getting this information but for the future I need to improve this. Do you have an alternative? I also can not use stored procedure, function inside SQL SERVER. I must do it with native query from Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
Declare @p table(pumber int,step int,bookdate datetime)
insert into @p values 
(1,1,'2019-01-01'),(1,2,'2019-01-02'),(1,3,'2019-01-03')
,(2,1,null),(2,2,null),(2,3,null)
,(3,1,null),(3,2,null),(3,3,'2019-01-03')

;With CTE as
(
select pumber,max(bookdate)bookdate 
from @p p1 
where bookdate is not null
group by pumber
)

select p.* from @p p
where exists(select 1 from CTE c 
where p.pumber=c.pumber and p.bookdate=c.bookdate)
union all
select p1.* from @p p1
where p1.bookdate is null and step=1
and not exists(select 1 from CTE c 
where p1.pumber=c.pumber)
```

If performance is main concern then 1 or 2 query do not matter,finally performance matter.

```
Create NonClustered index ix_Product on Product (ProductNumber,BookingDate,Stepnumber)
Go
```

If more than 90% of data are `where BookingDate is not null` or `where BookingDate is null`  then you can create Filtered Index on it.

```
 Create NonClustered index ix_Product on Product (ProductNumber,BookingDate,Stepnumber)
where BookingDate is not null
 Go
```

Comment: Adding indexes helped me . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `row_number()` with a proper ordering. Null values are treated as the lowest possible values by sql-server ORDER BY.

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES *
FROM myTable t
ORDER BY row_number() over(partition by PRODUCT_NUMBER order by BOOKING_DATE DESC, STEP_NUMBER);
```

Pay attention to sql-server adviced indexes to get good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the most efficient method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.step_number = (select top (1) t2.step_number
                       from t t2
                       where t2.product_number = t.product_number and
                       order by t2.booking_date desc, t2.step_number
                      );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(product_number, booking_date desc, step_number)`.